# Invalid conversion from utf8 string when it is in variable

Tags: windows, string, unicode, d

The effect here is that the message text is correct in greek letters but message title is all empty boxes, sometimes with other texts there are chinese chars.

```
string msg= "ένα μήνυμα";
MessageBoxW(null, "ένα μήνυμα", cast(wchar*)msg.toStringz, MB_ICONERROR);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`toUTF16z`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_utf.html#.toUTF16z) (from `std.utf`) when converting a `string` to a `LPCWSTR` instead of a cast:

```
MessageBoxW(null, "ένα μήνυμα", toUTF16z(msg), MB_ICONERROR);
```

You don't need to do anything with the string literal, because the compiler automatically creates a UTF-16 constant by looking at `MessageBoxW`'s argument type.

Comment: can the conversion `toUTF16z()` be done automatically when function request `LPCWSTR` without me invoking it in code every time ?

Comment: No (not unless you create your own custom string type). It would involve a hidden cost (an allocation) every time you used that feature, so it wouldn't be very good language design for a system language.

Comment: It seems that people tend to forget that Windows is using UTF-16 ... :). @rsk82 I would rather make MessageBoxW() a wrapper that forwards the call to WinAPI MessageBoxW with UTF-16 encoded string... Seems much better option to me, than having your own string type...